# Natural Earth: How to get the position of each country?

Tags: arcmap, arcgis-desktop, coordinate-system, coordinates, natural-earth

I've just split the [1:10m Natural Earth countries](http://www.naturalearthdata.com/downloads/) into individual JSON files which I plan to render and partially stitch back together using [RaphaelJS](http://raphaeljs.com/australia.html). The 1:10m map is very big (10mb or so) so loading it all in one go in the browser is not really feasible.

But how do I get the position of each country? Opening the 1:10m map in ArcMap's Attribute Table shows no signs of any latitude, longitude, X or Y or whatever.

Maybe this info needs to be extracted from an exported JSON of the full map using some JS virtual canvas / positioning system? I.e. for each of the individual countries that need to be stitched together, some server-side script would query the full JSON to get their paths?

Thanks!

Comment: in the most simple case a country is one polygon. the polygon is definded by pairs of lat/lon coordinates, where the last pair = the first pair (means polygon is closed). what do you mean with position? the centroid of that polygon?

Comment: How far have you gotten based on the suggestions in this thread? http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/25171/shapefile-to-svg-with-arcmap-while-retaining-country-attributes

Comment: @Kurt: Please see the update above.

Answer (score 1):

If it is just the XY coordinates (latitude/longitude, easting/northing, etc) then I would try the **[Add XY Coordinates](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//001700000032000000)** tool first.